# Two problems with an animation sequence code

Tags: c#

I have a code that will play an animation after another one has finished.
Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationSequence : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animation First;
    public Animation Second;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        First.GetComponent<Animation> ();
        Second.GetComponent<Animation> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (First.IsPlaying = false){
            Second.Play;
        }
    }
}
```

And I get two errors:

1. The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer
2. Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Which lines are the errors complaining about?

Comment: Line 19,13 and 20,3

Comment: and which lines are those in the code you showed us above?

Comment: if (First.IsPlaying = false){
  Second.Play;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
void Update () {
    if (First.IsPlaying = false){
        Second.Play;
    }
}
```

to

```
void Update () {
    if (First.IsPlaying == false){
        Second.Play;
    }
}
```

'=' is an assignment '==' is a comparison.
Or more idiomatic

```
void Update () {
    if (!First.IsPlaying){
        Second.Play;
    }
}
```

plus it seems like ISPlaying is a function. SO do

```
void Update () {
    if (!First.IsPlaying()){
        Second.Play;
    }
}
```

If you want isplaying to be a property then it has to be declared like this

```
class Player
{
....
    public bool IsPlaying {get;set;}
....
}
```

Comment: Okay. The second error is gone, but now i get this The `!' operator cannot be applied to operand of type `method group' when i changed the statement